# ASP.NET MVC 3 dropdown binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, razor

I encountered the next indexer syntax during binding my model with collection to view.

Here is what I have:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImportAction ImportAction { get; set; }
}

public enum ImportAction
{
    Skip,
    Add,
    Merge
}
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home"))
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
    {
        <span>Name: @customer.Name</span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Customers[index].ImportAction, customer.ImportAction.ToListItems())
        index++;
    }
    <button type="submit">
        Submit</button>
}
```

How to avoid this **[index]** usage? Any other correct syntax? Take to the look, that without it `@Html.DropDownListFor` would not work and update my model on post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the loop variable 'customer' like the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => customer.ImportAction)
```